# Jquery Slide after reveal filter

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, jquery-easing

I have a filter action that is working the way I want each div fades in or out on click; however when the divs fade out or in, instead of just jumping over I would like to see them slide into place.

http://theoaks.turnpostadmin.com/floor-plans/

What can I add to this to make that happen like a jquery.easing or something

Here is what I have thus far

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#filter a').click(function() {
      $(this).css('outline','none');
      $('#filter .current').removeClass('current');
      $(this).parent().addClass('current');

    var filterVal = $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(' ','-');

    if(filterVal == 'all') {
        $('ul#portfolio li.hidden').fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
    } else {

        $('ul#portfolio li').each(function() {
            if(!$(this).hasClass(filterVal)) {
                $(this).fadeOut('normal').addClass('hidden');
            } else {
                $(this).fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
            }
        });
    }

    return false;
     });
    });
```

Thanks

Jamie

Comment: I tried a could things but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

If you just want them to slide up and down rather than fadeIn and fadeOut, you can use  the built-in animations: `.slideUp()` and `.slideDown()`.

If you want them to first fadeOut and then slideUp, you could use this:

```
$(this).fadeTo('normal', 0).slideUp('normal').addClass('hidden');
```

You can't use `.fadeOut()` because when it's done, it hides the object which would keep  `.slideUp()` from working.  But, if you use `.fadeTo()`, it just changes the opacity and you can then run `.slideUp()`.

Comment: I want them to still fade in and out but slide as well. Sorry I forgot the url http://theoaks.turnpostadmin.com/floor-plans/

Comment: @Jamison - OK, my latest edits show you how to fadeOut and then slideUp.

Comment: That kind of worked but im looking for more of something like this 
http://silverio.sachagreif.com/category/portfolio/

I change the code above to what you suggested but it didnt work out well

http://theoaks.turnpostadmin.com/floor-plans/

Comment: @Jamison - what element in your page are you trying to animate?  Remember, we don't know your page or what you have to hover/click on to make something happen.

Comment: the floor plans need to fade and slide over. If you click on one bedroom or two bedroom or all the filter is applied